# Region Holes outer surface

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I have a following code:

```
    bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 
      1}, {-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, 1/2}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        1},{5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 5}}]}, 
   "RegionHoles" -> {{0, 0}}];
   bmesh["Wireframe"]


ToElementMesh[bmesh]["Wireframe"]
```

the output is:

[image]

How can we create mesh in the inner region and holes/empty at the exterior?

I need something like the following,

[image]

==================== Update ==================

How to have regionholes in the smaller rectangular region?

```
    bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {0.5, 1.1}, {1, 
      1.1}, {1, 1.6}, {0.5, 1.6}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        1}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 5}}]}];
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "RegionHoles"->None :

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 
      1}, {-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, 1/2}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        1}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 5}}]}, 
   "RegionHoles" -> None];
(*bmesh["Wireframe"]*)
ToElementMesh[bmesh]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

If you want to remove the outer part, you should start with a smaller boundary mesh region. Having a boundary line and a fully meshed inner region does not work with an ElementMesh. You might be able to do this with a MeshRegion - but you will not be able to use that for a finite element analysis.

Here is an example of a material region and a region hole:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 
      1}, {-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, 
      1/2}, {-4/5, -4/5}, {-3/5, -4/5}, {-3/5, -3/5}, {-4/5, -3/5}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        1}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 5}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 
        12}, {12, 9}}]}, "RegionHoles" -> {{-7/10, -7/10}}];
(*bmesh["Wireframe"]*)
ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Here the region touches the boundary and is correctly removed:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToElementMesh[
  RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
    Rectangle[{-1, -4/5}, {-3/5, -3/5}]], 
   Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}]], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005, 
  "RegionHoles" -> None]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

The mesh you want to use, if that's for finite element analysis then it's not valid. You can get very close to the boundary but not touch it.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToElementMesh[
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
   RegionUnion[Rectangle[{-99/100, -4/5}, {-3/5, -3/5}], 
    Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}]]], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005, 
  "RegionHoles" -> None]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: In the original problem, I need to have a fully meshed inner region and within a boundary line I have boundary conditions/ boundary contact lets say a small rectangle at right top and left bottom. So, that's why I want to have an empty boundary region, which has boundary conditions and inner fully meshed region. will I be able to use that for finite element analysis.

Comment: @MuhammadAli, I have trouble understanding what you need. Can you make a drawing?

Comment: I edited the question, can we have this? if not that's fine as well.

Comment: @MuhammadAli, we can have something like as a MeshRegion this but not as finite element mesh. What do you want to do with this? Also, the boundary conditions are not in contact with the domain - there are not really a boundary. I think what you really want is a full mesh in each region but different material coefficients in them.

Comment: I want to apply an electromagnetic field from the boundary conditions but they are not in contact with the domain and the outer region/unfilled is pure conductor. So, basically, I'll move the boundary conditions/contacts close to the domain, I see your point now (first time using the Finite Element Analysis). However, I was able to draw everything in Toboundarymesh (inner region and boundary conditions away from domain) but not the outer region.

Comment: @MuhammadAli, you'd need to mesh all of the domain. See for example [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1502006470)

Comment: Thanks! However, what if I only need a region hole at the boundary conditions? I am modifying the questions. The point is I should have regionholes at the boundary specified at the edges mostly.

Comment: Also, then it will be much easier to assign markers to the boundary only and to analyze the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadAli, see update. A region hole at the boundary is not possible - the would be equivalent to a cut out.